# After using .htaccess RewriteRule page not opening properly

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to convert my dynamic PHP link to a clear link; for that I used RewriteRule. But the work seems to be not done properly

I am trying to convert

```
dappersole.in/product.php?product_id=45;
```

To

```
dappersole.in/product/46;
```

Using

```
RewriteRule ^product/([0-9]+)$ product.php?prodct_id=$1 [NC,L]
```

After this the page does not load properly. But if I remove `product/` from `RewriteRule`, the page loads perfectly

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ product.php?prodct_id=$1 [NC,L]
```

```
dappersole.in/45;
```

Comment: there appears to be a spelling mistake in the re-write rule. You first mention `?product_id=45` but the rule uses `prodct_id=$1`

Comment: no it is product_id=45 not prodct my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your page won't load fully because you are referring to your CSS and JavaScript resources relative to the current location. You need to change this to refer to the resources relative to the root of the site. For example, change this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/slider-pro.min.css" media="screen"/>
```

to this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/slider-pro.min.css" media="screen"/>
```

Note the leading slash before `css/slider...`. You need to do this for **all** your CSS, jQuery and image resources. Alternatively, you can save time by adding the following to your `<head>` node:

```
<base href="/">
```

Or, even better:

```
<base href="http://dappersole.in/">
```

Additionally, I recommend you do the same with your `mod_rewrite` rule:

```bash
RewriteRule ^product/([0-9]+)$ /product.php?product_id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Lastly, I recommend you ensure `Multiviews` is not enabled, by adding this line to the top of the file:

```bash
Options -Multiviews
```

Comment: wow mn respect...It seems that you have a lot of knowledge on php....Worked perfectly.Finally after whole fu*king day it worked..Thanks a lot buddy

Answer (score 0):

I've had that same problem on an older version of apache / mod_rewrite and I never found out what the exact problem was. But it definitely did not like rewriting `/something/123` to `/something.php?...`.

The quick fix I used, was renaming my php file to `_something.php` and using that.

So in your case renaming `product.php` to something that does not start with `product` like `_product.php`:

```
RewriteRule ^product/([0-9]+)$ _product.php?product_id=$1 [NC,L]
                               ^ strangely enough this solved my problem...
```

Comment: that means i  have to change my file name form product to _product.

Comment: Still same mn,Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @jeroen - please see [my comment](/questions/38974845/after-using-htaccess-rewriterule-page-not-opening-properly/38976863#comment65306760_38975811) below.

Comment: Help me i'm totally stuck in this

Answer (score 0):

I too have had similar issues to this with Apache 2.2 - if the name and the rewritten name are very similar it fails. You could cheat slightly and use a different url such as `http://www.example.com/item/46`

```
RewriteRule ^item/([0-9]+)$ product.php?product_id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Similar naming issues can arise from the use of the `Multiviews` option, which uses content negotiation to serve files with ambiguous naming (for example, a missing file extension). Turning off Multiviews disables that, and rewrite rules will not be affected.

Comment: Whenever I tried `Options +FollowSymlinks -Multiviews` I get the dreaded 500 error message for some reason.

Comment: Not sure if `Options` is case-sensitive, but it should be `+FollowSymLinks` with a cap-`L`.